# Funções recursivas para concatenação de strings

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Olá. Basicamente eu possuo um DataModel que faz vínculo com ele mesmo, para gerar uma estrutura de hierarquia.

```
public partial class ProdutoGrupo
{
    public ProdutoGrupo()
    {
        ProdutoGrupos1 = new HashSet<ProdutoGrupo>();
        Produtos = new HashSet<Produto>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }        
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Imagem { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProdutoGrupo> ProdutoGrupos1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ProdutoGrupo ProdutoGrupoPai { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}
```

O que eu estou tentando é, através de uma função recursiva, concatenar os nomes dos grupos até que um deles não possua mais 'pai'.

Algo como:
Cueca / Algodao / Box

Eu não quero definir um máximo de níveis de hierarquia, mas sim deixar o usuário decidir vinculando um grupo a um pai.

O que eu tentei até o momento foi isso, mas sem os resultados esperados:

```
private static string RecursiveGrupoNome(DataModel.ProdutoGrupo grupo, string grupoNome)
{
    string _grupoNome = grupoNome;
    
    if (grupo.ProdutoGrupoPai != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(grupo.ProdutoGrupoPai.Nome))
    {
        _grupoNome = $"{grupo.ProdutoGrupoPai.Nome } / {grupoNome}";
        return grupoNome = RecursiveGrupoNome(grupo.ProdutoGrupoPai, grupoNome);
    }

    return _grupoNome;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que recursão não seja uma estratégia adequada para resolver este problema. Claro que é possível fazer isso com recursão, mas um laço simples vai resolver o problema mais naturalmente na minha visão e, com certeza, o código vai ficar mais legível.

Segue exemplo:

```
using System;

class Program 
{
    public static void Main (string[] args) 
    {
        Grupo grupo1 = new("Grupo 1", null);
        Grupo grupo2 = new("Grupo 2", grupo1);
        Grupo grupo3 = new("Grupo 3", grupo2);
        Grupo grupo4 = new("Grupo 4", grupo3);

        Console.WriteLine(ObterNome(grupo4));
    }

    private static string ObterNome(Grupo grupo)
    {
        if (grupo is null) return "";
       
        var nome = grupo.Nome;

        while (grupo.GrupoPai is not null)
        {
            grupo = grupo.GrupoPai;
            nome += $" / {grupo.Nome}";
        }

        return nome;
    }
}

record Grupo(string Nome, Grupo? GrupoPai);
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/pt-so567674#main.cs).

Comment: Verdade. Eu acabei bitolando em uma solução e não vi uma muito mais simples que estava do lado. Obrigado pela resposta!